# Destination host unreachable

Tags: networking, ping

I have two computers on my local lan network. When I ping the local IP of computer 2 from computer 1, it prints Destination Host Unreachable (or to any other device). Same happens when I try to ping from the second device to the first one.

I tried turning off the firewall on both devices, didn't work.

The DHCP list on the router shows both devices correctly.

---

```
ping  192.168.2.105

Pinging 192.168.2.105 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.2.100: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.2.100: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.2.100: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.2.100: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.2.105:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

---

arp -a

```
 Interface: 192.168.2.100 --- 0x8
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.2.1           ec-e6-a2-11-ff-c0     dynamic
  192.168.2.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.0.0.250           01-00-5e-00-00-fa     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

Comment: Try temporarily as a test to disable the firewall.

Comment: what kind of router are you using?    Wired or wireless?   I am guessing both hosts are windows machines?

Comment: already did @harrymc.

Yes, both are windows machines, the connection is wired.

Comment: Hard to tell, without more information. Some router/switches have an option to block traffic within the LAN (e.g. Cisco's protected ports feature), but there may also be a defect somewhere. Can both computers ping the default gateway (192.168.2.1)?

Comment: What is the router ? Does it have some device isolation features ?

Comment: It's called fiberhome  (it's from the ISP), but no it doesn't have device isolation, and I believe it shoudn't matter for a ping between 2 devices on the same lan.

They can both ping 192.168.2.1